# Event Tracking for Newsletter Sign Up

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I want to track how many people sign up for Newsletters. I can do it with event tracking in Google Analytics. But there is an issue. I found the below code on the button

```
<form name="ccoptin" action="http://visitor.r20.constantcontact.com/d.jsp" target="_blank" method="post" onsubmit="return SubscribeValidate()">
```

Then where I have to place the following code

```
onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'newsletter signup', 'email', 'Sidebar',, false]);"
```

Answer (score 1):

onClick is tracking for buttons.  For forms, add the code into a successful "validate" function and/or on the "thank you" page.

```js
var SubscribeValidate = function () {
  // Make sure the form is filled out
  if ($("#email").text() != "") {
    return false;
  }

  // Track in Google Analytics
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'newsletter signup', 'email', 'Sidebar', , false]);

  window.location = "/thanks"; // or $("#modal").modal();
}
```

Comment: I have a submit button and I used the code here. Is it Ok? <input type="submit" name="go" value="Submit" class="buton_gray"
onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'newsletter signup', 'email',
'Sidebar',, false]);">

Comment: It's fine, but you're only counting "submit" button clicks at this point instead of "newsletter signups" (aka the event will fire even if they never typed in their email).